# Python map object getting exhausted/consumed?

Tags: python, dictionary, object, return-value

#### Backdrop

While *fiddling* with the [`map()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) in my **Python** project, I tried to assign a variable, the python map object I intended to create once, and then reuse the same map object to use them as strings, lists or tuples, etc.

##### Brief reproduction of the problem:

```py
def concat(n):
  return n + "abc"
def upp(Lst):
  for i in Lst:
    if i[0].isupper():
      return i
def low(Lst):
  for i in Lst:
    if i[0].islower():
      return i

#main
L = ["a","B","c"]
m = map(concat,L) #Creating a Python map object
print(f"Capitalised string: {upp(list(m))} lowercased string: {low(list(m))}") #Accessing the returned manipulated map object
```

##### Expected Output:

```
Capitalised string: Babc lowercased string: aabc
```

#### Problem:

##### Actual output:

```
Capitalised string: Babc lowercased string: None
```

```py
#Manual Debugging:
u = upp(list(m))
l = low(list(m))
print(u,l)
```

Output:

```
["aabc","Babc","cabc"][]
```

So as you can see, the second time I try to retrieve the map object, it doesn't return anything in the list.

#### Final Question:

I want to know why is it so that the map object is not accessible even when it does exist.

##### Note:

1. The following questions don't answer my question:

   - [Map function not returning a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55989586/map-function-not-returning-a-value) because:

     I. Not related to ***`Python`** map object*.

     II. There the map object does return some value but it isn't being used properly.
   - [map function isnt returning the values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61519618/map-function-isnt-returning-the-values) because:

     I. Not related to Python

     II. The map function object does return some value there.
   - [Python - Printing Map Object Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52157057/python-printing-map-object-issue) because:

     I. Much related to my question but still has not proper/relevant references/citations to materials explaining the reason(s) of it being treated as a consumable object.
   - [Python: casting map object to list makes map object empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45017937/python-casting-map-object-to-list-makes-map-object-empty) because:

     I. Not enough citations to documentations clearly stating the fact.
2. Edits which improve the sample program which reproduces the problem will be welcomed.

Comment: `map` returns a generator, once a generator is fully consumed it will not yield anymore values when iterated. You need to re-create the generator to iterate over it again

Comment: @IainShelvington I looked up the generator concept, but you see, I need to access the returned value multiple times, and possibly in different forms every time. So won't creating a `map` generator eveytime I need it add up to the code overhead? Is there a way we can evade re-creating it everytime?

Comment: You could just convert it to a list initially so you can re-use it: `m = list(map(concat,L))`. Then you don't need the calls to list in your string formatting